# VM options incorrect in intellij?

Tags: java, linux, javafx, java-8, javafx-11

I am working on a project, and I have been following the process I have always used in the past to import JavaFX for course projects, add the /lib/ to the project structure and edit the build VM options. For some reason I am getting this error:

```
Unrecognized option: --module-path
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Any tips as to what might be going on here would be greatly appreciated, I am using javafx-sdk-11.0.2 and jdk1.8.0, which has worked on many past projects for me if I am remembering correctly.

And here are the VM options:

```
--module-path /path/to/my/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.conrols,javafx.fxml
```

...Even with Running in Java-11-openjdk

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.conrols not found
```

Comment: I think you have a conflict between a version of java before 9 (before Jigsaw project and modularity) and a newest version of java (explaining `--module-path` which was introduced in java 9 thus)

Comment: Also JavaFX 11 is not compatible with JDK 8.

Answer (score 2):

`--module-path` was introduced to [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) as part of the [Jigsaw Project](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/).

Try launching your VM using a version of Java equal or above to [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9)

Comment: Interesting, now I get a new issue that I was trying to solve before I stumbled into this issue.

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question with the new problem if you really can't get it fixed @slick_57 ! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here was the mismatched java versions, although now there is new issue regarding javafx.controls, even with --module-path defined